# Celery Tasks for Flask App in Google Cloud Run

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, redis, celery, google-cloud-run

I have have two services deployed onto Cloud Run from docker containers. One is my python flask app using gunicorn. The other is my celery service. I have connected my celery service to a Google cloud Redis memory store instance using a serverless VPC connector.

However, my celery tasks don't seem to be registering or executing when called by my Flask service.
Is it possible to manage celery tasks this way? I've seen numerous other posts recommending the Google Task Queue. However if it is possible, I rather stick to using celery.

Comment: There's a [doc](https://docs.saaspegasus.com/deployment.html#google-cloud-run) saying that Celery is not yet supported in Cloud Run. My suggestion is that you deploy your service on GAE Flex or Compute Engine. If VM cost is an issue, then use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview#http)

Comment: Is the memory store instance showing entry for your tasks? Make sure your Flask app is pointing to the correct redis instance

Comment: @dishantmakwana how can I check this? I've only got one redis memorystore instance which I believe I have configured correctly and pointed my flask app too using the correct broker url. But when I look at the instance on the cloud console I don't see any traffic (presumably because no calls to the service are being made).

Comment: In addition of @DonnaldCucharo comment, you can also use GKE Autopilot if you already have a  container.

Comment: @James have you solve it?

Comment: @JT_T unfortunately it doesn't seem possible. I am instead deploying to AWS and using ElastiCache for redis

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure now but this seems to work, isn't exactly Flask but the idea should be pretty similar to implement:

1. On the container create a "special entry point".
2. This entrypoint
   shoud do something like:

- raise celery workers in a parallel thread, eg. unix should be like **celery whatever &**
- raise a dummy server listeting on the cloud run port, if python is available it can be **python -m http.server --directory /dummy 8000**

here some snippets:

**Dockerfile**

```
...
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sudo chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
elif [ "$ENV_TYPE" == "celery-worker" ];
then
  echo "Running celery worker command with dummy server for CloudRun"
  pipenv run celery -A etl worker -l info &
  pipenv run python -m http.server --directory /dummy 8000
elif [ "$ENV_TYPE" == "celery-beat" ];
then
  echo "Running celery beat command with dummy server for CloudRun"
  pipenv run  celery -A etl beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler &
  pipenv run python -m http.server --directory /dummy 8000
```

**CloudRun setup**

[image]

Comments:

- Looks like everything is working properly... but I haven't tried this with load really.
- It will be great to run the entrypoint as a one-liner in the entrypoint command of GCR. But looks like it simple fails, I think simply isn't compatible to do in that way.
- The dummy server is to allow the container not to fail the automatic, hard coded and innevitable Google Cloud Run healthcheck.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: This solution can be tricky, as of the celery fails the cloud run continue to work with only the python server which respond that everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to use two containers in one cloud run:

- the first one contains a simple server web responding HTTP 200, because the cloud instance must respond at least to the first container startup probe
- the second contains the celery beat

Compared to the solution with two process in the same container, the cloud run can detect if the celery process is exited and restart the cloud run instance.

A possible improvement is to have the server web doing a celery ping when receiving a HTTP startup probe request.

```
        apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          annotations:
            run.googleapis.com/ingress: internal
            run.googleapis.com/ingress-status: internal
          labels:
            cloud.googleapis.com/location: us-west2
          name: worker
        spec:
          template:
            metadata:
              annotations:
                autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '1'
                autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale: '1'
                run.googleapis.com/startupProbeType: Default
            spec:
              containerConcurrency: 20
              containers:
              - command:
                - "python"
                - "-m"
                - "http.server"
                - "8080"
                name: dummy
                image: python:3.11
                ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
                  name: http1
                resources:
                  limits:
                    cpu: 100m
                    memory: 200Mi
                startupProbe:
                  initialDelaySeconds: 10
                  timeoutSeconds: 5
                  periodSeconds: 240
                  failureThreshold: 1
                  httpGet:
                    path: /
                    port: 8080                      
              - command:
                - /run_worker.sh
```